# Approval process that does field update will not start the process builder: Looking for alternative

Tags: process-builder, approval-process, flow, field-update

As listed in other posts, I see many people have this issue, where an approval process is to do a field update and then expect that update to start a flow. I'm in the same boat. Are there any workarounds or alternatives?

My use case: When an opp status changes to x, before trigger to set status to hold and start approval process, when approved update status to original x value. Process Builder, when status is updated check field y (if else update 1 or 2 based on data.). I cant get the PB to fire and I need to run this flow when status changes. What are my options???

Comment: Did you check reevulate workflow rules in approval process field update.

Comment: Yes, However its still wont work.